# how to show image from server in javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, io

I am making Thumbnail View pages.

I stored thumbnail images external folder(C:/temp/image) and I get them from server as byte data.

now I want to convert this data into image in javascript and show in HTML.

so I tried to make blob URL using these byte data. But I got error **"FILE NOT FOUND"**

Here is my code. Please let me know what i'm missing

(It is Spring boot and angular.js )

***Service***

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> listRecentWithInfo( int userid) throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> recentList = dashboardDao.listRecentWithInfo( userid);

    for (Map<String, Object> map : recentList) {
        int dashboardid = (int) map.get( "DASHBOARDID");
        FileInputStream is = null;
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao= null;
        byte[] imageByte = null;
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> res = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());

        if (thumbnailDao.findOne( dashboardid) != null) {
            String path = thumbnailPath + thumbnailDao.getOne( dashboardid).getFileName();

            is = new FileInputStream(path);
            bi = ImageIO.read(is);
            System.out.println(bi.getType());
            bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bao);
            imageByte = bao.toByteArray();
            res = new ResponseEntity<>(imageByte, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        map.put("THUMBNAIL", res);
    }
    return recentList;
}
```

***js***

```
$http.get("app/dashboard/recentWithInfo").then( function( rtn) {
    rtn.data.map(item=> {
        if (item.THUMBNAIL) {

            var bytes = new Uint8Array(item.THUMBNAIL.body / 2);
            for (var i = 0; i < item.THUMBNAIL.body; i += 2) {
                bytes[i / 2] = parseInt(item.THUMBNAIL.body.substring(i, i + 2), /* base = */ 16);
            }

            // Make a Blob from the bytes
            var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: 'image/png'});
            var imageUrl =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(imageUrl);
            item.THUMBNAIL = imageUrl;
        }
    });

    $scope.items = rtn.data;
        console.log(rtn.data);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**I Got a solution By myself**

I realized that I can convert Byte Data into Base64 just like that

```
 "data:image/png;base64," + item.THUMBNAIL.body;
```

and this BASE64 encoded data can be used as Image source in HTML!